# Update backbone model with new json

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-model

Right now, I'm passing json to model like this:

```
model m = new app.SomeModel(json);
```

and then using it, which seems fine.

However, now whenever my json changes, I want to pass the new json to the model, without creating a new instance of the model, something like:

```
m.updateJson(json);
```

EDIT: Right now I'm doing something like:

```
m.set(json)
```

But can we also do something like:

```
m.set("json_key",json)
```

So that later on I'll be able to do:

```
m.get("json_key")
```

to get the entire json ?

Comment: may help you - http://backbonejs.org/#Model-set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use model.set, it will trigger "**change**" events, and update dependent objects

> setmodel.set(attributes, [options])  Set a hash of attributes (one or
>   many) on the model. If any of the attributes change the model's state,
>   a "change" event will be triggered on the model. Change events for
>   specific attributes are also triggered, and you can bind to those as
>   well, for example: change:title, and change:content. You may also pass
>   individual keys and values.
>
> note.set({title: "March 20", content: "In his eyes she eclipses..."});
>
> book.set("title", "A Scandal in Bohemia");

And If you need to trigger "**sync**" event, after you have updated a model issue
*model.trigger("**sync**")*

Comment: I have read this, but my problem is my json is big, and I can't set each attribute individually, so I was trying to update the whole json in 1 go !!

Comment: Set supports this, look at the sample note.set({title: "March 20", content: "In his eyes she eclipses..."}); this updates 2 fields simultaniously

Comment: Can we also use model.set like this:
note.set("json_key",json_value);
where json_value = {title: "March 20", content: "In his eyes she eclipses..."} ?